# Checking 2 database tables for user login

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I am using the following code:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '%s' and password = '%s'", $email, $password);
```

I want to accomplish the following:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM database1.users AND database2.users WHERE email = '%s' and password = '%s'", $email, $password);
```

I need to check for the possibility that a user exists in either table.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: I'm sure there is a smart way to do this in SQL, but you *could* just do it in your PHP code... that would also make it easier to handle the case that there's a valid user in *both* tables.

Comment: Please do not do this. **ALWAYS** use [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will eventually end up in serious trouble. `sprintf` is not the proper way to assemble queries.

Comment: This is just a code sample. The variables have previously been passed through this function: `function sanitize($variable) {
    $variable = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($variable));
    return $variable;
}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `UNION` to combine both queries:

```
SELECT * FROM database1.users WHERE email = '%s' and password = '%s'
UNION
SELECT * FROM database2.users WHERE email = '%s' and password = '%s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query can be as follows:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1 JOIN table2
ON table1.userID=table2.userID WHERE email=? AND password=? LIMIT 1
```

It's very dangerous to append variables to an SQL query, and while you are well-meaning on using sprintf, it does not accomplish what you are intending. Use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to properly guard against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(A.UserFound*B.UserFound=0,'No','Yes') Authenticated
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) UserFound FROM database1.users
    WHERE email = '%s' and password = '%s'
) A,
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) UserFound FROM database2.users
    WHERE email = '%s' and password = '%s'
) B;
```